# Determine the print-size of a string containing escape characters

Tags: c++, ansi-escape

I'm trying to make a progress bar which would resize according to the space left on screen. The progress bar consist of a title string followed by the bar and few trailing numbers:

```
15:23:11 [SampleElement] SampleElement.cpp:25: Finding bin index... [###########] 100% (14K it/s)
```

In principle this is a pretty straight forward task since the print-size can be directly deduced by the size of the title + the size of the pBar.

However when the title string contains escape characters (like colors for example) doing `title.size()` does not only returns the printed size on screen, but also the non printed characters. My question is: **Is there a way we can simply compute the print-size of any string?**

Comment: Can you show a sample input?

Comment: You mean ANSI escape codes? You might iterate manually over the string, detect the start sequence and if so skip counting until end sequence is detected. Possibly you might count string lengths already *before* inserting the escape codes.

Comment: Yes, like this one: `"\033[1;31m"`which enables the red color. Is there a std:: function which would do the triming job for me? It's true I could make an example but I think it would be kind of overwhelming for the actual question

Comment: Also: the code structure does not allow me to count the string size before inserting the ANSI codes

Comment: Then, yould should then your code structure so that it is easier to do what you want to do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to search for ANSI terminal escape sequences since they have a unique pattern. Incidentally, there is a C function called [`isprint(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) to check for printable characters.

Combining these two, you should be able to create a function that can count printable characters in a string. (Assuming that the terminal in question supports
the ANSI escape codes/sequences, of course.)

```cpp
// The following only works with C++11 or above

// ...
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <regex>

// The regular expression is brought outside the function in order to avoid compiling it multiple times during each call to 'count_no_escape'
std::regex ansi_reg("\033((\\[((\\d+;)*\\d+)?[A-DHJKMRcf-ilmnprsu])|\\(|\\))");

std::string::iterator::difference_type count_no_escape(std::string const& str) {
    std::string::iterator::difference_type result = 0;
    std::for_each(std::sregex_token_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), ansi_reg, -1),
        std::sregex_token_iterator(), [&result](std::sregex_token_iterator::value_type const& e) {
                                          std::string tmp(e);
                                          result += std::count_if(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), isprint);
                                      });
    return result;
}
```

> **Small Note**: The regex for checking ANSI escape sequences was built using [this webpage as reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20190624214929/http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm):

The above function tokenizes the string using the ANSI escape codes as delimiter. After extracting all potential substrings, the printable characters are counted in each of them and the sum total result is returned.

Now you can use it like this:

```cpp
// ...
std::cout << count_no_escape("\033[1;31mabcd\t\n\033[7h") << std::endl; // 4
// ...
```

If you'd like to try it for yourself, here you go:

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/9Pbv9nhdv)